# Embedded Excel via iframe open a specific sheet by default

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, aspose-cells

I have embedded a excel via iframe. But the problem is the iframe will default show the last workbook in the excel file.

However, the excel file is created by back-end using aspose-cells, since aspose-cells will default add a copyright workbook in the excel as the last workbook. So it is possible to let set default preview first workbook or remove the copyright page create by aspose-cell?

Answer (score 0):

A worksheet with evaluation watermark will always show as the active worksheet in the generated excel file using Aspose.Cells library. Only in licensed version, you can set the active worksheet to other worksheets.

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.